# How can I MongoDb querying to list sub array for referenced entities by pagination and sorting?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, pagination

I have an array such as `exams collection` including sub-array by Reference to `students collection` on MongoDB as given below

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "name" : "Exam #1",
    "students": [
      "student_id" : "s231",
      "student_id" : "s2342",
      ....
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "name" : "Exam #2",
    "students": [
      "student_id" : "s134",
      "student_id" : "s12",
      ....
    ]
  },
 ... 
]
```

At first, I need a quick solution of listing k students ( with their detail information from students collection) by pagination.

Consequently, I need a solution of listing k students by sorting with their  names and pagination

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Are you sure in `students` array there is `property` and `value`? I think it suppose to be : `students : [{student_id:1},{student_id:2}]` which is an array of objects

Comment: In your query you only seem to be interested in the students collection, and not the exam collection.  Is that your intention, or is the question just badly worded?

Comment: For specific exam take the students information with pagination and sorting, you are right.

Comment: Can you please remove the "scary numbers" from the question. There is absolutely no utility at all in retrieving 2000 documents each with 1000 items in an array, even with "sorting and paging" on the array items. You realistically would be displaying a single page of data for a single exam, and then possibly "paging" through the array results. So stating it otherwise is misleading, either to others or to yourself. Also please show a real sample of data, since your presentation of `student_id` witin the array is not even a valid data structure. Make it valid and keep it to truly  needed.